# Java split and replace are not working as expected, removing more than regex limiters

Tags: java, regex, string, swing, user-interface

I was writing a program and noticed that in certain cases I would run into an exception. I have isolated the problem to my split and replace methods and ran a test in the main method. Code is as follows.

```
public class tester
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //create text box
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15,10);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setText("");
        panel.add(textArea);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        String s = textArea.getText().replace("[a-z]", "");
        String[] parts = s.split("\\=|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\+|\\[a-z]");
        JButton b = new JButton("something");
        panel2.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
        textArea.setText(s);
        }  
    });
}
}
```

Specifically at the line in which

```
        String s = textArea.getText().replace("[a-z]", "");
        String[] parts = s.split("\\=|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\+|\\[a-z]");
```

the regex limiters are used.

Typing a test input into the textArea with a string such as 123asdv1+asd-

The expected output once the button should be pressed should be the string:
1231+- when s is called.

However, actual output once pressed is in fact an empty string, blank.

parts is used in my original program to store the numbers into a double variable for use in a calculation, but it was added here for sake of consistency.

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me what i've done wrong, my original program is meant to fetch all the numbers between a special symbol such as + or - to be stored and used for a calculation. If an illegal operation was met,  it would print an error message onto the text area and continue from where it left off before the error, this is where I am running into the problem.

Comment: Please boil down your example to the smallest possible test case (MCVE)

Comment: Note `\\[a-z]` matches `[`, then `a-z]` as a char sequence. If you meant `[a-z]`, remove the backslash. But it looks redundant if you use `String s = textArea.getText().replaceAll("[a-z]", "")` (you use `.replace` that does not use regex).

Comment: Thank you for better informing me on how regex works, as for the smallest possible test case. It occurs at the specific line in which I have showing the replace and split methods. The rest of the code is to provide a reproduceable example with a GUI. It can be tested using a button. since my original code was a gui.

Comment: Also since you are already using character class `[...]` and rest of your alternations are just single symbols you can add them to that character class instead of manually writing all those alternations. So instead of `\\=|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\+|\\[a-z]` you can write `[a-z=/*+-]` (I placed `-` at the end so I wouldn't need to escape it since there it can't represent any `x-y` range, but you can also write it as `[a-z=\\-/*+]`)